# Shift register implementation with arbitrary shift amount

Tags: vhdl

I want to develop a shift register in VHDL for a processor. In the Instruction Register (IR) of processor there is a section that determines the shift amount. Now I want to check it to implement this operation.

For example, bit numbers 5 to 10 show the shift amount. If there is "000001" in this section, when the timing signal t1 occurs the shift register should function and the t2 timing signal arrives.

But why does the following code not show any effect on the shift register when running with modelsim?

```
IF sc=t1 AND R2 (10 DOWNTO 5)= "000001" THEN
R2<=R2(62 DOWNTO 0) & R2(63);
END IF;
```

Comment: This code snippet is not enough to understand the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Stackoverflow uses a structured format that's introduced in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) provides guidelines for [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) questions. VHDL is strongly typed, depending on elaborated declarations and processes (including from elaborated concurrent statements) interconnected by nets in a design hierarchy requiring an [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) providing stimuli with a clear and specific problem none of which your question demonstrates as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is correct. Since in VHDL is always better to use as most constant values as possible, so synthesis can be easier I would write a code for your case

```
process(clk, reset)
begin 
  if reset then
   --reset everything 
  elsif posedge(clk) then 
  if sc = t1 then 
    case R2(10 DOWNTO 5) 
      when "00001" => 
        R2 <= R2(62 DOWNTO 0) & R2(63)
      when "00010" =>
  end if
end process
```

The above code is just an idea of what needs to be done. We need to shows more of the actual code you are using.

Comment: So many thanks for your response. My written code was correct. In fact I had mistake somewhere else that I found it. I should compare shift amount which is in Instruction Register, not R2.